# What is the correct way to use the latex-firstaid package?

Tags: packages, ulem, varwidth

I have just noticed the [`latex-firstaid`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/latex-firstaid) package for patching other packages. Should `latex-firstaid` be loaded before or after the packages that it patches? Or some other way? The package documentation doesn't seem to say how to use it.

If it matters I want to use `latex-firstaid` with `ulem` and `varwidth`.

Comment: don't load it, it will load itself as needed

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`firstaid` is not a latex package to be loaded with `\usepackage` it is a feature built in to recent latex formats that maintains a list of contributed packages that need adjustments for recent latex releases.

It is distributed on ctan separately to `latex-base` so that the list of packages and their fixes can be modified without requiring a new latex version and an update to `base`. however it is essentially an integral part of the format, not a contributed latex package.

Comment: Thanks. It would be good if the `firstaid` package made this clear.

Comment: @DocOctal the link you put in your question says "...this package is meant to be loaded during format generation and not by the user. " which is bascally all I say here?

Comment: facepalm I didn't read the instructions on the CTAN page. The `firstaid` package pdf does say why it's a separate bundle but doesn't seem to explicitly say the user shouldn't load. Unless I missed it again.